# i18n for array elements of react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, internationalization

I would like to use `universe:i18n` for translating my meteor application (using react).

In this component you can see, that I iterate through an array using `map()` and as the output I would like to get the categories as translations:

**imports/ui/components/example.jsx**

```
import React, { Component }                 from 'react'
import i18n                                 from 'meteor/universe:i18n'

class Example extends Component {
    getCategories(index) {
        const categories = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]; // <-- Get correct translations of these elements
        return categories[index - 1];
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="content">
                { this.props.sections.map((i) => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            { this.getCategories(i.index) }
                        </div>
                    );
                }) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**i18n/de.i18.json**

```
{
    categories: {
        one: 'Eins',
        two: 'Zwei',
        three: 'Drei'
    }
}
```

I tried to do it with

```
const T = i18n.createComponent()

class Example extends Component {
    getCategories(index) {
        const categories = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]; // <-- Get correct translations of these elements
        return categories[index - 1];
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="content">
                { this.props.sections.map((i) => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <T>categories[{ this.getCategories(i.index) }]</T>
                        </div>
                    );
                }) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work, because you have to use dot instead of bracker notation, so

```
<T>categories.{ this.getCategories(i.index) }</T>
```

Instead of

```
<T>categories[{ this.getCategories(i.index) }]</T>
```

But it still won't work, because it will create an `children` array, but only string is accepted, so use it like this:

```
<T children={`categories.${ this.getCategories(i.index) }`} />
```

[Source](https://github.com/vazco/meteor-universe-i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n.js#L106).